# Git remove branches

Tags: git, git-branch

Can I remove branches using the commands below?

Local branch:

```
git branch -d <branchName>
```

Remote branch:

```
git push origin --delete <branchName>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

One thing you should be aware of is that `-d` is a "safe" delete: it'll only let you delete a branch that's merged in to your current `HEAD`. If you want to delete *any* branch, use `-D`:

```
git branch -D <branchName>
```